# Select by multiple values in left join

Tags: mysql

Working with following structure, how can I select a subset of `request`s respecting multiple conditions in this 1:n relation?

```
# Table 1: Request
uid
name

# Table 2: Additional Information
uid
type
value
request
```

Note for table 2: `type` can be anything, i.e. 'product_name' or 'rating'.

If I'd just want to select Requests by a given `product_name` I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM request as r 
    LEFT JOIN additional_information as i 
    ON r.uid = i.request 
    WHERE i.type = 'product' AND i.value = 'Product Name'
```

I'm stuck at what my statement must look like if I want to select Requests by a given `product_name` AND `rating`. I have tried to simply add another join but this gave me all requests that related to a given `product_name` as well as all requests related to a given rating. I need the statement to respect both conditions.

This, as mentioned, does not work for me.

```
SELECT * FROM request as r 
    LEFT JOIN additional_information as i 
    ON r.uid = i.request
    LEFT JOIN additional_information as a 
    ON r.uid = a.request 
    WHERE i.type = 'product' AND i.value = 'Product Name' 
    OR a.type = 'rating' AND a.value = 1
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move those conditions from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` condition like

```
SELECT * FROM request as r 
    LEFT JOIN additional_information as i 
    ON r.uid = i.request
    AND i.type = 'product' AND i.value = 'Product Name'    
    LEFT JOIN additional_information as a 
    ON r.uid = a.request 
    AND a.type = 'rating' AND a.value = 1;
```

And Yes absolutely, considering the valuable comment (which missed) from Strwabery, instead of doing a `select *` or `select r.*` you might actually want to specify the column names you want to fetch which is better than `*` performance wise since you are not getting unnecessary data using projection; unless you really want to fetch everything.

Comment: @TheF and name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: While this works, the query seems extremely slow, while working with less than 500,000 records. Any way to optimize the query?

Comment: @TheF, that depends on how well your tables are indexed. post your tables complete definition along with this suggested queries explain plan.

Comment: Adding in index for uid,type,value in the additional information table improved the performance dramatically. Thanks, I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be slow from the other offering since it is joining to your additional data TWICE, once for product, again on rating.  This should probably be changed to a single left-join otherwise you could get a Cartesian result bloating your answer.

```
SELECT * 
   FROM 
      request as r 
         LEFT JOIN additional_information as i 
            ON r.uid = i.request
           AND (   ( i.type = 'product' AND i.value = 'Product Name' )
                OR ( i.type = 'rating' AND i.value = 1 );
```